# Escaping a sed expression to execute over ssh from Python

Tags: python, bash

I have a file on a remote server that needs to have a line updated in it. I am trying to do the update via python but appear to be having a character escape issue.

The line in the file I am trying to update is:

```
BEGRCVDDATE=02/01/2018 00:00 am
```

The line of code in python script I am using to try and make the update:

```
os.popen('ssh %s sed -i s/'BEGRCVDDATE=[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]'/'BEGRCVDDATE=%s'/ %s' % (ip, rcvdate, file_path))
```

The above code is throwing the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown option to `s'
```

I am however able to run the sed command outside of the python script which leads me to believe this is a character escaping issue. Below works outside of the python script.

```
ssh <ip> "sed -i s/'BEGRCVDDATE=[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]'/'BEGRCVDDATE=BEGRCVDDATE=03\\/08\\/2018 00:00 pm'/ /tmp/test.txt"
```

I have tried various combinations of quotes and back-slashes to try and get around the issue I am seeing without success.

If anyone can help me resolve the issue I am seeing it would be much appreciated.

Note: due to python version in my environment os.popen is being using instead of subprocess.

Comment: This is not valid python syntax. Can you please double-check that you copy-pasted your code exactly?

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module, then you can pass the arguments as a list rather than worrying about trying to get quoting correct

Comment: @EricRenouf, ...use of `ssh`, unfortunately, means there still *is* worrying about quoting that needs to be done. SSH effectively concatenates its arguments together with `"$*"` and passes them as a single string to the remote shell. But better one layer of shell evaluation than two.

Comment: Even with `subprocess`, you have to make sure that the string you define from `ip` et al. is a correctly escaped `sed` command.

Comment: @EricRenouf as I stated above, due to the version of python in my environment, subprocess is not available to me.

Comment: @TylerHelder, which *specific* version is that? We need to be able to look up which facilities you *do* have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 2.6.6. actually I take that back, i just tried to import it and it worked. I had thought subprocess wasn't introduced until 2.7. I will give you below solution a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess, pipes

# Generate your list of arguments *as a list of Python strings*
rcvdate = '02/01/2018 00:00 am'
cmd=['sed', '-i',
     's@BEGRCVDDATE=[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]@BEGRCVDDATE=%s@' % (rcvdate,),
     file_path,
]

# Ask Python itself to correctly form a shell command from that list
cmd_str = ' '.join([pipes.quote(s) for s in cmd])

# Pass that shell command as an argument to `ssh`.
subprocess.call(['ssh', ip, cmd_str])
```

...or, if you *truly* don't have the `subprocess` module, you'll need a second round of shell escaping:

```
ssh_cmd = ['ssh', ip, cmd_str]
ssh_cmd_str = ' '.join([pipes.quote(s) for s in ssh_cmd])
os.system(ssh_cmd_str)
```

---

Note that I changed your `sed` expression to use `@`, not `/`, as a sigil. This means that literal backslashes are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I appreciate all of your help. The above fixed the issue I was seeing.